# VMware Server Host-Only Network Routing

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing, nat, vmware-server, rras

I have a windows 2008 web server machine running VMware server. I have 3 VM's - All 3 are test servers so security isn't really a concern... each of them running windows 2008 standard and some of them serving web content.

My ISP only allows one MAC address to access the physical switch, however they give me 10 public IP addresses to use. My question is, if I put each VM on their own Host only network, how can I route all traffic from a specific public IP on the host, to the corresponding host only adapter, therefore routing to the specific VM?

For example:

A single physical Adapter on the Host has the following public IP's assigned to it in windows networking:

- 74.208.14.10
- 74.208.14.20
- 74.208.14.30

Each VM is on a host-only network

- vm1 - 192.168.196.1
- vm2 - 192.168.197.1
- vm3 - 192.168.198.1

On the host, I want to route all traffic from **74.208.14.10 to VM1** and **74.208.14.20 to VM2** and **74.208.14.30 to vm3** without using VMware NAT, or bridged connections. I want each server to appear to have its own public IP address. My guess is i can modify the route tables somehow, or perhaps in ICS...but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're only allowed one MAC address you are looking at some kind of NAT solution. Instead of using VMWare's builtin network config, I would add a 4th VM, and set it up with a light firewall applicance (The vmware appliance download page has several of these). Set up this VM as your single outside mac address and configure rules accordingly. This will give you more options than the builtin vmware networking options.

Still, the easy way is just do have them enable more mac addresses for you. Even if there's an added cost to this, i bet it beats a quirky network setup, especially in the long run.

Comment: The MAC address of the HOST is the only one that can be added to the switch. They will not let me add other MACs.

Comment: they wont let you "trade" your host mac for another? I'd start looking for another ISP...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using host only adapter use bridged mode and configure public IP directly on VM.

Comment: like i said above, i can not do that. My isp only allows one MAC address to connect to the switch.

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution, a rules in iptables if you VMWare installe in Linux, you can used any rules tu IPtable forward Static IP Public to Privated IP VM host. when i try it i can reponse anyway